# Select 'N' rows and get number of rows using Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Currently we have a page where we need pagination so for that i need 2 info 
    1. Get total number of rows 
    2. Fetch 'N' number of rows

Currently i am doing it with 2 query, for step 1 something like

```
 count = db.Transactions
           .AsNoTracking()
           .Where(whereClause
           .Count();
```

And then

```
db.Transactions
           .AsNoTracking()
           .Where(whereClause
           .Skip(skipRows)
           .Take(pagesize)
           .ToList();
```

Is there is any way to optimize it?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [Local Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592872.aspx):

```cs
// Load all Transactions with filtering criteria into the context
db.Transactions.AsNoTracking().Where(whereClause).Load();

// Get Count
var transcationsCount = db.Transactions.Local.Count;

// Paging
var pagedTranscations = db.Transactions.Local.Skip(skipRows).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

This should only result in **one** database query being fired to the database in the initial `Load()` call.

Comment: i guess it would be more costly operation, loading all data in memory is not an option, row count is very large

Comment: I think it depends on where do you want to put your **cost**, your code will hit the database twice (which is network bound). If you do it my way, you will be memory/CPU bound. You should do a more detailed profiling to see where the bottleneck is and decide on where to optimise.

Answer (score 1):

This will return you an IQueryable and you can do queries against that, each will be executed to the db. This way you don't have to rewrite the query each time you want to query something.

```
var query = (from t in db.Transactions
            where whereClause
            select t);

var count = query.Count();

var items = query
            .Skip(skipRows)
            .Take(pagesize)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: That i am already doing in my project,i am more concerned towards performance.

Comment: Performance of what? Obviously if you have just 100 or so items in the transactions, loading them once in memory and doing what ever will be faster than accessing db twice depending on latency and db performance. How ever when the row count reaches certain point it will be more cost efficient to execute 2 queries.

Comment: Query is expected to fetch millions of rows and that is why it needs pagination if it would have been in thousands this question would not have been here.